# Initializing Select2 inside of Highslide

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2, highslide

I have a corporate web mail service and I use `Twitter Bootstrap Modal Window` in order to compose and answer emails online. Such a `Modal Window` contains 2 `Select2` elements for TO and CC fields, usual `input` field for a subject, textarea and Send button.

I was looking for a different type of popup window for that and I decided to use `Highslide` instead of `Modal` as with `Highslide` I can switch focus back to the main page, open more windows with emails in the same time, move the `Highslide` windows around etc.

So I took my modal content and saved it as a separate html page and I'm getting it with a ajax request but I can't figure out now how to initialize Select2 and other elements as those needs to be initialized at the page load and I renger the `Highslide Window` later as opposite to `Modal Window` that was alway present on the page.

Here what was my original **index.php** whith `Modal Window` working:

```
 <table id="datatable">
    // ajax table with all the emails
</table>

<div id="modal-email" class="modad hide fade">
//here is email form goes...
    <label>TO:</label><input id="email-to" />
    <label>CC:</label><input id="email-cc" />
    <label>Subject:</label><input id="email-subject" />
    <textarea id="email-body" />
    <button>Send</button>
</div>

$('#email-to').select2({
    // initialization parameters
});

$('#email-cc').select2({
    // initialization parameters
});

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#datatable').delegate('tr', 'click', function() {
        fill_email_values();
        $('#modal-email').modal('show');
    }
});
```

So now I took the `#modal-email` and moved to a separate file

**email.form.html:**

```
<label>TO:</label><input id="email-to" />
<label>CC:</label><input id="email-cc" />
<label>Subject:</label><input id="email-subject" />
<textarea id="email-body" />
<button>Send</button>
```

and I have modified the **index.php** file into:

```
<table id="datatable">
    // ajax table with all the emails
</table>

<div class="highslide-html-content" id="highslide-form-email">
    //form will get inserted here with hs.htmlExapnd command
</div>


$('#email-to').select2({
    // initialization parameters
});

$('#email-cc').select2({
    // initialization parameters
});

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#datatable').delegate('tr', 'click', function() {
        $.ajax ({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'email.form.html',
            success: function(data) {
                return hs.htmlExpand(null, { 
                    contentId: 'highslide-form-email', 
                    maincontentText: data  
                });
            }
        });
        fill_email_values();
    }
});
```

Obviously when I had `Modal Window` loading with the **index.php** page I could initialize all the elements including Select2 but now when I'm loading the **email.form.html** later only after a click occurs then initial `Select2` initialization fails because the elements does not exists yet. However I can't initialize the Select2 later when I put out the popup form as I belive those needs to be initialized on Document Ready or something like and this time has past by. How can I do this?

Comment: So when you load page, content of modal should be loaded to highslide ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan No, I have replaced modal wiht highslide, so I need Selec2 initialized inside of highslide after it gets inserted (posted) into highslide.

Comment: 1) You can catch [onAfterExpand](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterExpand) and add content
2) See this examples http://www.roadrash.no/?page_id=13 which use the ajax calling